# Spring security configure 2 kind of login behaviors - ajax response JSON & form login redirect new page

Tags: spring-security

I have form login the work great for browser user login:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.csrf().disable().cors()                                                   
        .and().authorizeRequests() 
        .antMatchers("/api/**").authenticated()                                       
        .anyRequest().permitAll()                                                      
        .and().formLogin().loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error")              
        .usernameParameter("username").passwordParameter("password")                   
        .successHandler(loginSuccessConfig)
        .failureHandler(loginFailureConfig)         
        .and().logout().logoutUrl("/logout")                                           
        .logoutSuccessHandler(logoutSuccessConfig)
        .logoutSuccessUrl("/index");
}
```

But I do like another kind of login through AJAX and response JSON instead of redirect to another page.
May I know it is possible have another login path "/api/login", because successHandler and failureHandler can't differentiate what response should be provide since no some kind of indicator to do so.

Hope someone can guide on this.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just think of simply hack by submitting additional parameter in the login form or Ajax

```
<input type="hidden" name="responseJson" value="true"/>
```

Then, in extends the "SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler" class (any other as you like), inside override "onAuthenticationFailure" method, this method got param call "HttpServletRequest", check as below:

```
String responseJson = request.getParameter("responseJson"); 
if (responseJson != null && responseJson.equals("true")){
    response.setContentType("text/json");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
    out.print(jsonObjectAboutFailLogin.toString());
    out.flush();
}
```